# How to show first 5 divs only with "Load more" button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have code below, everything runs great. But if I insert that script code to  the script doesn't work. No errors in console. Why? In Fiddle everything runs great. It's because of wrong version of Javascript?

```
<div class="param-filter-single">
   <form method="post">
      <fieldset class="parametric-filter">
           <strong>Hlavní</strong>
           <br>
           <div class="param-filter-single-cell">One</div>
           <div class="param-filter-single-cell">One</div>
           <div class="param-filter-single-cell">One</div>
           <div class="param-filter-single-cell">One</div>
           <div class="param-filter-single-cell">One</div>
           <div class="param-filter-single-cell">One</div>
           <div class="param-filter-single-cell">One</div>
           <div id="loadMore">Load more</div>
           <div id="showLess">Show less</div>
     </fieldset> 
   </form>
</div>

<style>.param-filter-single .param-filter-single-cell {display: none}</style>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    size_li = $(".param-filter-single .param-filter-single-cell").size();
    x=5;
    $('.param-filter-single .param-filter-single-cell:lt('+x+')').show();
    $('#loadMore').click(function () {
        x= (x+5 <= size_li) ? x+5 : size_li;
        $('.param-filter-single .param-filter-single-cell:lt('+x+')').show();
    });
    $('#showLess').click(function () {
        x=(x-5<0) ? 3 : x-5;
        $('.param-filter-single .param-filter-single-cell').not(':lt('+x+')').hide();
    });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You need to include **jQuery**, which is included in JSFiddle by default.

Comment: Hm, if I include that with file, the whole site is broken. So, there isn't another way, how to do it without jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is your solution.

```js
var text = $('.pureyad'),
     btn = $('.purgex'),
       h = text[0].scrollHeight; 

if(h > 120) {
 btn.addClass('less');
 btn.css('display', 'block');
}

btn.click(function(e) 
{
  e.stopPropagation();

  if (btn.hasClass('less')) {
      btn.removeClass('less');
      btn.addClass('more');
      btn.text('Show less');

      text.animate({'height': h});
  } else {
      btn.addClass('less');
      btn.removeClass('more');
      btn.text('Show more');
      text.animate({'height': '120px'});
  }  
});
```

```css
   .pureyad {
        max-width: 600px;
        line-height: 1.1em;
        font-family: 'Roboto Slab';
        overflow: hidden;
        background: #46988f;
        font-size: 14px;
        height: 120px;
        padding-left: 20px
    }

    .purgex {
        display: block;
        background: transparent;
        border: none;
        border-top: 1px solid #222;
        width: 585px;
        max-width: 100%;
        font-family: 'baloo bhai';
        font-size: 15px
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pureyad">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
                </div>
<center><button class="purgex">Show more</button></center>
```